# Android-Studio: Github --credentials get: GitHub: command not found

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I was trying to upload my project to GitHub on Android-Studio.
Pushing to GitHub master... process never ends and Version Control Console gives this Error:

```
GitHub --credentials get: github: command not found 
'C:\Users\SA'EED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git-askpass-2722525787662236837.bat" "Username' 
is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I only find an empty repository on my GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the latest version of GitHub, check your git path.
Settings->version Control -> Path to git-executable

It should be something like -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Note this may vary upon where you have installed GitHub.

Try

> Test

It should be a success. Try to push your code again.

If this does not work try solution 2

Solution 2:

Simply make a copy of your project(copy and paste) in some other location. Delete the .git physically from the new copy. Import the new copy into android studio again. Go to version control System(VCS)->Import into Version Control->Share project on github or bitbucket(whichever you have set up). Then enter master password and new repository name. Then your setup is complete and push your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answer you're looking for in this post: http://jrxie.blogspot.de/2014/02/github-credentials-get-github-command.html

**tl;dr**: you want to add your equivalent of the following folder to your PATH.

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LNKHAB6L.QR1\LP7D7JB2.E6Z\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0000_c74cce3a838f9354
```

The folders inside `Apps\2.0` are probably named differently, but you shouldn't have any problems finding the right ones.